# How can I build an outpost in State of Decay?

Tags: state-of-decay

How can I make or get an outpost? What kind of things do I need and how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

To create an outpost in State of Decay you need to completely clear a building of zombies, inside and partially around the exterior.  Once it is secure you open up your radio comms and you can select to set it as an outpost (Establish Outpost).  It does cost Influence so it's best to scavenge some supplies and take them back to your main base before attempting to do it.

The outposts can be upgraded to have defensive capabilities so are useful to place around key roads leading to your main base, that way they can handle hordes without your intervention.  This does cost fuel however to setup.

If you've just started the game then there are certain requirements you need to meet before you can do this.  Taken from the link at the bottom:

> In State of Decay, this radio call is unlocked after the player
>   completes mission Lay of the Land.
>
> In Breakdown, this radio call becomes available after the player is
>   settled into a home site (at level 1) or right at the beginning (from
>   level 2, since the RV acts as a temporary home site and has 2 outpost
>   slots).
>
> In Lifeline, this radio call is available right from the beginning,
>   even before the player reaches the Black Friday base.

[Establish Outpost](https://stateofdecay.fandom.com/wiki/Establish_Outpost)